# Meaning of continuous family of cones.

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, definition, ricci-flow, convex-cone

While reading about Ricci flow from Andrews and Hopper's book, I came across this notion of a continuous family of cones in a vector space $V$.

I didn't find the definition for this notion in the book and couldn't find the definition elsewhere either. Can someone tell it means for a family of cones $C(s) \subset V$ to be continuous?